# Titanium: NullPointerException while creting New Mobile App project and while running existing project

Tags: android, titanium

I am working or rather trying to work on an android project using titanium I am getting this exception when I try to create a new Mobile App,

I am using

```
Titanium SDK: 3.2.1GA,
```

also tried: `mobilesdk-3.2.2.v20140214120903-win32`

and `mobilesdk-3.2.1.v20140206170116-win32`

because somewhere it said that this is a [bug](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-4454?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Also tried working with jre 1.6 (32-bit) coz I read that it doesnt support 1.7 [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132008/cannot-launch-simulator-through-titanium#answer-230377)

Added jre6 path in system path variable, but still Im unable to get my Hello world project in titanium thanks

here is the stacktrace of error When I click the finsh button on the new project wizard

```
!ENTRY com.aptana.projects 2 0 2014-02-17 14:59:05.908
!MESSAGE Internal error: 
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: 
    at com.aptana.projects.wizards.AbstractNewProjectWizard$1.run(AbstractNewProjectWizard.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2327)
    at com.aptana.projects.wizards.AbstractNewProjectWizard.doCreateProject(AbstractNewProjectWizard.java:321)
    at com.aptana.projects.wizards.AbstractNewProjectWizard$2.run(AbstractNewProjectWizard.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.startProcess(ProcessUtil.java:589)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.doRun(ProcessUtil.java:527)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.doRun(ProcessUtil.java:462)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.run(ProcessUtil.java:445)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.run(ProcessUtil.java:407)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:302)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:403)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommand(NodeJSExecuter.java:221)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommandWithNoLogin(NodeJSExecuter.java:431)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.login(NodeJSExecuter.java:466)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:255)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:403)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommand(NodeJSExecuter.java:221)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommandLoggedIn(NodeJSExecuter.java:444)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.internal.cli.NodeTitaniumSDKCommandsHandler.createProject(NodeTitaniumSDKCommandsHandler.java:124)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.ide.wizard.NewMobileProjectWizard.finalizeProjectCreation(NewMobileProjectWizard.java:143)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.wizard.BasicNewTitaniumProjectWizard.createNewProject(BasicNewTitaniumProjectWizard.java:300)
    at com.aptana.projects.wizards.AbstractNewProjectWizard$1.run(AbstractNewProjectWizard.java:249)
    ... 5 more
!SUBENTRY 1 com.aptana.projects 4 0 2014-02-17 14:59:05.909
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.startProcess(ProcessUtil.java:589)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.doRun(ProcessUtil.java:527)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.doRun(ProcessUtil.java:462)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.run(ProcessUtil.java:445)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.run(ProcessUtil.java:407)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:302)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:403)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommand(NodeJSExecuter.java:221)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommandWithNoLogin(NodeJSExecuter.java:431)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.login(NodeJSExecuter.java:466)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:255)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:403)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommand(NodeJSExecuter.java:221)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommandLoggedIn(NodeJSExecuter.java:444)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.internal.cli.NodeTitaniumSDKCommandsHandler.createProject(NodeTitaniumSDKCommandsHandler.java:124)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.ide.wizard.NewMobileProjectWizard.finalizeProjectCreation(NewMobileProjectWizard.java:143)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.wizard.BasicNewTitaniumProjectWizard.createNewProject(BasicNewTitaniumProjectWizard.java:300)
    at com.aptana.projects.wizards.AbstractNewProjectWizard$1.run(AbstractNewProjectWizard.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2327)
    at com.aptana.projects.wizards.AbstractNewProjectWizard.doCreateProject(AbstractNewProjectWizard.java:321)
    at com.aptana.projects.wizards.AbstractNewProjectWizard$2.run(AbstractNewProjectWizard.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

This is the exception when I right click the sample project, Run as -> choose emulator:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-02-17 16:16:18.021
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching Titanium Android Emulator - Kitchen Sink".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.startProcess(ProcessUtil.java:589)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.doRun(ProcessUtil.java:527)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.doRun(ProcessUtil.java:462)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.run(ProcessUtil.java:445)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessUtil.run(ProcessUtil.java:407)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:302)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:403)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommand(NodeJSExecuter.java:221)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.runCommandWithNoLogin(NodeJSExecuter.java:431)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.login(NodeJSExecuter.java:466)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.cli.NodeJSExecuter.run(NodeJSExecuter.java:255)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.launching.AndroidNodeJSCommandsHelper.build(AndroidNodeJSCommandsHelper.java:285)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.launching.AndroidNodeJSCommandsHelper.run(AndroidNodeJSCommandsHelper.java:167)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.internal.cli.NodeTitaniumSDKCommandsHandler.run(NodeTitaniumSDKCommandsHandler.java:490)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.launching.AndroidSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(AndroidSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Edit:

Stack trace after TI worked surprisingly, see comments for details:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-02-22 12:14:51.010
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-02-22 12:14:52.663
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the images from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commandImages' extension point.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-02-22 12:14:52.663
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.run_on_device.android'
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-02-22 12:14:52.663
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.debug_on_device.android'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2014-02-22 12:15:09.805
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: com.appcelerator.titanium.alloy.internal.ui.AlloyTemplateInstaller$1

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2014-02-22 12:15:09.807
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: com.appcelerator.titanium.alloy.internal.ui.AlloyTemplateInstaller$3

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2014-02-22 12:15:09.808
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55
!SESSION 2014-02-22 12:15:10.882 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_25
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-02-22 12:15:42.606
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the images from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commandImages' extension point.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-02-22 12:15:42.606
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.run_on_device.android'
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-02-22 12:15:42.606
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.debug_on_device.android'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 4 0 2014-02-22 12:15:45.837
!MESSAGE CSS property 'maximize-visible' has been deprecated: renamed as swt-maximize-visible

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 4 0 2014-02-22 12:15:45.842
!MESSAGE CSS property 'minimize-visible' has been deprecated: renamed as swt-minimize-visible

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.ide 4 0 2014-02-22 12:18:39.726
!MESSAGE (Build 3.2.1.201402041146) [ERROR] com.appcelerator.titanium.core/debug/dashboard Unknown SDK ios

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core 4 0 2014-02-22 12:23:47.848
!MESSAGE There are no Android devices connected

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2014-02-22 12:41:22.681
!MESSAGE NLS missing message: MobileUsageUtil_mobile_event_error in: com.appcelerator.titanium.usage.messages
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: @FD_ added full stack trace

Comment: ok just after starting the bounty and after leaving titanium for one week, it has started to work. The things that I remember I did, installed adt-bundle and created a few emulatores and while I ran titanium one of the emulators was running, does anybody get an idea of what was wrong?

Comment: Could you check where the node executable is in the preferences, and if your installation of node is working and updated?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it helps someone, since Im not sure of it myself, I have added the successful log as well.

Things which I can think of made it work:

1. I removed the extra switches added in the TitaniumStudio.ini file, for bypassing authentication in the splash screen.
2. Installed the adt bundle and created an emulator and ran it, maybe it did some configurations which titanium was unable to do.

the above steps resolved the exception